# Walrus operator in Python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, walrus-operator, python-assignment-expression

When I use the walrus operator as below in the Python(3.9.6)
interpreter,

```
>>> walrus:=True
```

I get a syntax error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    walrus := True
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How is this different from the following?

```
>>> print(walrus := True)
```

Comment: Assignment expressions must be enclosed in parens. They work inside function calls like this, though, similar to how bare generator expressions must be enclosed but can be passed in a function call, e.g. `sum(x for x in some_iterable)`.

Comment: This is just how it's degined.  See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases

Comment: I meant designed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's different because the Python core developers were *very* ambivalent about violating [the Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) guideline "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it", and chose to make it inconvenient to replace most uses of plain `=` with `:=` without adding additional parentheses to the expression.

Rather than allowing `:=` to replace `=` in all contexts, [they specifically prohibited](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) unparenthesized top-level use of the walrus:

> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level of an expression statement.
>
> ```
> y := f(x)  # INVALID
> (y := f(x))  # Valid, though not recommended
> ```
>
> This rule is included to simplify the choice for the user between an assignment statement and an assignment expression – there is no syntactic position where both are valid.

In many cases where `:=` is prohibited, you can make it valid by adding otherwise unnecessary parentheses around the expression, so:

```
(walrus:=True)
```

works just fine, but it's enough of a pain that the assumption is that most people will stick to the simpler and more Pythonic:

```
walrus = True
```

in that scenario.